# git commit queue tool

Tags: git, continuous-integration, buildbot

Our team and project got really big and we can no longer sustain it. So we decided to do the right thing and move to continuous integration. As a first step, we dumped clearcase and moved to git. This made our lives significantly easier. However we still suffer from broken builds.

Now I am looking for a tool which would queue up all the commits, test them against multiple platforms and if they pass land them on the master branch. In an ideal world the tool would have a web interface and hooks for code review tool.

I know buildbot does some of this, but not all. I could write the tool myself; but the transition needs to be super smooth and relatively quick.

PS: Chromium and webkit projects seem to do exactly what we want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) could be configured to do this. See the [Android patch workflow](http://source.android.com/source/life-of-a-patch.html) for an example, and note that you could set up buildbot to be the "verifier", and if you don't care about code review (though you should!) you can set Gerrit to not require review or just make buildbot set the review flag too.

It seems Jenkins has a [Gerrit plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger).